# PHP parse_url doesn't work with array element

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $urls = file('urls.txt');
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        print(parse_url($url));
    }
?>
```

parse_url takes string as argument but not array element with type string. What should I do?

Comment: your code will throw `Notice: Array to string conversion ...`

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference between a string and an array element of type string.

Your problem is most likely that `file()` by default includes in each array element the newline at the end of each line in the file. See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

You're going to need to use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` to make it not do this (see link for details)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a different approach when reading the file.  Take this example:

```
$fp = fopen('urls.txt', 'r');
while(($buffer = fgets($fp, 1024)) != NULL){
   //where 1024 is maximum length of each line in file
    if(gettype($buffer) == 'string'){
        echo "$buffer\n";
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

Hope this helps you.